# create Pandas Dataframe with unique index

Tags: python, pandas

Can I create a dataframe which has a unique index or columns, similar to creating an unique key in mysql, that it will return an error if I try to add a duplicate index?

Or is my only option to create an if-statement and check for the value in the dataframe before appending it?

EDIT:

It seems my question was a bit unclear. With unique columns I mean that we cannot have non-unique values in a column.

With

```
df.append(new_row, verify_integrity=True)
```

we can check for all columns, but how can we check for only one or two columns?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`df.append(..., verify_integrity=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to maintain a unique *row* index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
dup_row = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40]], columns=list('ABCD'), index=[1])
new_row = pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,40]], columns=list('ABCD'), index=[9])
```

This successfully appends a new row (with index 9):

```
df.append(new_row, verify_integrity=True)
#     A   B   C   D
# 0   0   1   2   3
# 1   4   5   6   7
# 2   8   9  10  11
# 9  10  20  30  40
```

This raises ValueError because 1 is already in the index:

```
df.append(dup_row, verify_integrity=True)
# ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: [1]
```

---

While the above works to ensure a unique *row* index, I'm not aware of a similar method for ensuring a unique *column* index. In theory you could transpose the DataFrame, append with `verify_integrity=True` and then transpose again, but generally I would not recommend this since transposing can alter dtypes when the column dtypes are not all the same. (When the column dtypes are not all the same the transposed DataFrame gets columns of `object` dtype. Conversion to and from object arrays can be bad for performance.)

If you need both unique row- and column- Indexes, then perhaps a better alternative is to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) your DataFrame so that all the unique column index levels become row index levels. Then you can use `append` with `verify_integrity=True` on the reshaped DataFrame.

Comment: This will help, for this current situation because the rows are unqiue in total. However I think I was unclear in my question. With columns I meant that a column only can have unique values. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

OP's follow-up question:

> With df.append(new_row, verify_integrity=True), we can check for all columns, but how can we check for only one or two
>   columns?

To check uniqueness of just one column, say the column name is `value`, one can try

```
df['value'].duplicated().any()
```

This will check whether any in this column is duplicated. If duplicated, then it is not unique.

---

Given two columns, say `C1` and `C2`,to check whether there are duplicated **rows**, we can still use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

```
df[["C1", "C2"]].duplicated()
```

It will check row-wise uniqueness. You can again use `any` to check if any of the returned value is `True`.

---

Given 2 columns, say `C1` and `C2`, to check whether **each** column contains duplicated value, we can use apply.

```
df[["C1", "C2"]].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated().any())
```

This will apply the function to each column.

---

#### NOTE

```
pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan],
              [ np.nan, np.nan]]).duplicated()

0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

`np.nan` will also be captured by `duplicated`. If you want to ignore `np.nan`, you can try select the non-nan part first.